# origin of the expression "all over him/her like a cheap coat/suit"

Tags: etymology

I would like to know what is the origin of the expression "all over him/her like a cheap coat/suit". I Googled for it but didn't find any relevant entry. Anyone?

Comment: I think it must be a synonym for "unflattering".

Comment: It's long been a cliche of Australian football to say that a player clumsily infringing another through close bodily contact, was _all over him like a cheap suit_. The meaning of which I took to be that while a cheap suit covers the body it does so in a clumsy inelegant manner.

Answer (score 3):

I think it's mainly a BrE expression--a variant is *all over him like a rash*--commonly used to denote the excessive attention one person gives to another, usually when they've only just met, as a result of a sudden sexual attraction. I suppose it could be used about either sex, but I've only heard it used about a female in pursuit of a male. And the suit metaphor makes it tend that way in any case. Why it should be a "cheap suit" is less obvious, but one characteristic of an expensive suit is that you don't notice you're wearing it. If it's cheap, it's likely to be ill-fitting, made of abrasive material, and continually making its presence felt.

Comment: [Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=like+a+cheap+suit%3Aeng_us_2012%2C+like+a+cheap+suit%3Aeng_gb_2012&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clike%20a%20cheap%20suit%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clike%20a%20cheap%20suit%3Aeng_gb_2012%3B%2Cc0) says it's used more often in the U.S., although it's certainly found in the U.K. as well.  And I certainly recognize it.

Comment: I recognize it well enough. It's got currency in the U.S.

Answer (score 2):

There are many varients of this colorful phrase indicating unwelcome harassment: he was all over me like white on rice (popular in the South); all over him like flies on s***; all over him like stink on poop, like mud on pigs, like mustard on a hot dog, like fleas on a dog, etc.

Comment: I've never seen flies on s***. Only on shit. I wonder if the asterisks attract them?  ;-)

Answer (score 1):

A quick search shows the phrase dates to at least to the 1970s, as quoted in *[The Miami News](http://news.google.com/newspapers?nid=2206&dat=19740323&id=O9klAAAAIBAJ&sjid=CvQFAAAAIBAJ&pg=3277,1873333)* (Mar 23, 1974):

> Exuding boyish Innocence, he described how, upon arriving at the apartment building, she had invited him for coffee and then "was all over me like a cheap suit."

It's taken from a review of a TV movie called *[A Case of Rape](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Case_of_Rape)* by NBC, which premiered on February 20, 1974.

Answer (score 1):

It means to cling, not to hang as an expensive suit would be crafted.